# Making a styled ListView over an element such as iOS

Tags: android, listview

I have a SearchView inside my Layout. In this layout, I have my ListView associate with the SearchView. When I edit my SearchView, I have the right result.

But I what my ListView to over the other element of my screen (such as a button). How do I do that ?

I see that it's what's done on iOS.

to sum up : I need the listView to be under my searchView AND in front of all other element (the list does not have to move down the reste of my layout)

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="20dp">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/layoutDepart">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="@drawable/background_input_no_padding"
            android:weightSum="1"
            android:id="@+id/layoutSearchViewDepart">
            <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
                android:id="@+id/searchDepart"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/colorWhite"
                app:iconifiedByDefault="false"
                app:defaultQueryHint="Arrêt de départ"
                app:queryHint="Arrêt de départ"
                android:layout_weight="0.95"
                android:padding="0dp"
                android:layout_margin="0dp"

                >

                <SearchView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    />
            </android.support.v7.widget.SearchView>
            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#3a4770"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                />
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                tools:ignore="UseCompoundDrawables"
                android:tag="favArretItineraire"
                android:id="@+id/favDepart"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="@string/mes_favoris"
                    android:textColor="@color/bleuFonce"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:paddingStart="10dp"
                    android:paddingEnd="10dp"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_star_yellow_24dp"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/mes_favoris"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/resSelectionLigneDepart"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:background="@color/grayBg"
            android:layout_below="@id/layoutSearchViewDepart"
            >

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/listSearchViewDepart"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:divider="@null"
                android:dividerHeight="0dp"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:translationZ="15dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When deciding what view to draw on top, android respects two things:

- order in which views appear in the layout (next one is drawn over
  previous one)
- Z-coordinates - view with higher Z is drawn over view with lower Z

Note!
Old devices (below 21) do not use Z-order, only view order.
New devices (21 and above) use Z-order first and (for views with equal Z-coords) view order.

Your layout may look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="20dp">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/behindListViewWrapper"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <!-- here goes everything that should be behind listview, for example button -->

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="A button behind"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="#f00"/>

    </FrameLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listSearchViewDepart"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#7000"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
        android:id="@+id/searchDepart"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#fff"
        app:defaultQueryHint="Arrêt de départ"
        app:iconifiedByDefault="false"
        app:queryHint="Arrêt de départ"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

**Why Button is wrapped in additional FrameLayout?**
Because widgets can have default Z-coords. For button Z is equal 2 in normal state and 8 in pressed state (see https://material.io/design/environment/elevation.html). So in all cases the button will be drawn on top.
But that can be bypassed by wrapping button in other layout.
When desiding what to draw next, layout looks only for its direct children, not whole hierarchy. In this case all children have Z equal to 0, therefore `behindListViewWrapper` is the first to draw, then listview, then searchview.

If the button was not wrapped, it would be drawn on top (on modern devices, because of Z) or behind (on old devices, because of view ordering).

Comment: Very complete answer, I'll try it asap and i'll let you know. Thx